# How can I mount a microsoft LDM partition in ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop?

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive

I have recently installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS in on ssd but it is not showing my hard drive. Please help what should I do ??

Content of fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=3324ea01-3f72-4545-a6e2-2adaa27db9cf /               ext4      errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=B8EC-BE88  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb8 during installation
UUID=73282d5c-ea54-4fa5-87e6-131170bda499 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=337146ad-3c72-4d67-9196-078a54d7c0bb none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sudo fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 287048C0-F707-413A-8B36-8486CDF3E572

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      34       2081       2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2    2082     262177     260096   127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3  262178 1953525134 1953262957 931.4G Microsoft LDM data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FB17DBA8-AECB-4A2B-B88B-2D4FF2A39D89

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2    1024000   1228799    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3    1228800   1261567     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4    1261568 411787596 410526029 195.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb5  467761152 468858879   1097728   536M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb6  411789312 419600383   7811072   3.7G Linux swap
/dev/sdb7  419600384 448229375  28628992  13.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb8  448229376 467761151  19531776   9.3G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS? or Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS? or something else.  What have you used to look?  `blkid` `fdisk`, `gparted`, `gnome-disks` or something else?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS. I used gnome disk and my hard drive is showing in that but I cannot mount it .

Comment: When I click on "Other Places" only my ssd shows up. No hdd

Comment: Please edit your post with a copy and paste of the lines in your /etc/fstab file. Is the ssd mounted in fstab? A suitable entry might be: # SSD
UUID=b195263c-cf66-4dfa-8e40-9b3b586523f4 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: Edited . Please check

Comment: When I attempted to reformat what you posted, it looked like the UUIDs were all commented out.  I edited it to how it should look.  Please confirm that it matches what you have.

Comment: @Béné I just posted the output. Please check it out

Comment: The problem why you can't see your harddrive (/dev/sda) is that it's not a "normal" ntfs partition but a Microsoft LDM partition that apparently isn't natively supported by 18.04. It *is* possible to mount it though, check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108676 Unfortunately I know nothing about that partition type and therefore can't help you any further. Please edit the title to someting like "How can I mount a Microsoft LDM partition". Like that someone more knowledgable might find your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt install ldmtool
sudo ldmtool create all
```

For persisting the mounted LDM in Ubuntu, create the file `/etc/rc.local` and copy the code as below.

1. To create the file:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/rc.local
   ```
2. Content:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   ldmtool create all
   exit 0
   ```
3. Make the file executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
   ```

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JM7BG9tZhAg

Actually watching video will help you understand what you've done.

Comment: Thanks dear, you really save our time <3