# I can't get the UUID of my partitioin to mount it

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I want to mount `NTFS` partition of `Dual-boot` on Ubuntu `20.04` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978746) but I can't get the `UUID`~ can you please tell me how can I do that? thanks in advance.

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sda3

/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="LDM data partition" PARTUUID="1ac8435c-9d24-11e9-ae6f-1856807279f5"

$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LX015-1U71
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C2D7B6B3-7446-4292-8878-B7EBA2689DB0

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      34       2081       2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2    2082     262177     260096   127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3  262178 1953525134 1953262957 931.4G Microsoft LDM data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: LDM is dynamic partitions which is proprietary to Microsoft. There are some LDM tools in LInux, but much better to convert back to basic partitions. LDM was another work around to the old MBR 4 partition limit. But with gpt there is no need for LDM. How did you manage to convert to LDM? https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758

Answer (score 0):

https://linuxhandbook.com/get-uuid-disk/

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

I recommend you put it into `/etc/fstab` so you don't have to mount manually every time. Just fill in the correct folder and UUID for your case and just add this line to the end of the file.

`UUID=XXXXXXXXX /home/my/folder ntfs    nofail,auto       0       0`

You can also try to mount from GUI. Open files > Other Locations and you should see the drive partitions

[image: looks like this]

As pointed out by mook765 it requires a new tool to be able to use that LDM partition.

Comment: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` doesn't show the `sda` partitions at all!

Comment: what about `sudo fdisk -l` from the link? does that not show the partition?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, as you can see I see the partition, but not the UUID.

Comment: @Bilal This is a Windows ldm disk, you will need to have the package `ldmtool` installed on your machine. But I can't tell you what do do further, I don't use ntfs or ldm. Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227285/590937).

Comment: @mook765 thanks to your excellent remark, the link you have shared plus this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/912075) have solved my problem.