# Only One Drive (Partition) is Showing in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, disk, disk-management

**I recently set up a dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu. When I'm in Windows, I can see all of the drives (partitions) that I have on my computer. However, when I boot into Ubuntu, it only shows one drive.

Has anyone run into this problem before? If so, how did you fix it?

I've done some research and it looks like the issue might be related to Ubuntu not recognizing certain file systems. Is there a way to make sure that Ubuntu can read all of my partitions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
**
[In Windows boot it showing all of the partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfan4.png)

[In Ubuntu It only showing combined one. But other drive doesn't included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYn1t.png)

Comment: Are your Windows partitions encrypted?  Add requested info to your original posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mount a microsoft LDM partition in ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227285/how-can-i-mount-a-microsoft-ldm-partition-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-desktop)